# How I can transform a input characters to a different characters in a output? Datapower IBM

Tags: web-services, ibm-datapower

In Datapower, I need to create services that receive input with "N" characters that must be transformed to other characters. For example:

```
Input: <name> Francisco</name>
       <lastname>Pomodore</lastname>

Output: <name>aaaaaabb</name>
        <lastname>tststs</lastname>
```

I think that this problem is solved by using policy rules in the transform tool. However, I am not sure.

Comment: How does this question pertain to Bluemix?

Answer (score 0):

Add a Processing Policy with a Transform Action and a XSLT that does the needed transformation.